# What can be the solution to the error mentioned below?

Tags: python

I am accessing the record list in function submit from the result function but it is giving an error. I have mentioned the error. I have also tried to make a record list global but it is still giving me an error. Anyone can help?
It is the sample code. I am using the same logic in a project which has a requirement to access the record list in submit function from the result function.
Is there anyone who can suggest some appropriate solution to this error?

```
def submit():
    for i in record:
        for j in i:
            if(j=='bread'):
                p=int(i[1]) * 3
    print(p)
def result():
    global record
    record=[('bread','50'),('cake','200'),('cold drink','20')]
a=sumbmit()

###ERROR###
    for i in record:
NameError: name 'record' is not defined'''
```

Comment: please provide a reproducible code snippet, it is easier to tell the issue this way.

Comment: The error is quite clear, `record` is not defined before you try to use it in `submit`

Answer (score 0):

You define `record` in `result()` but you never call it, so why would you expect `record` to be defined when you call `submit()`? You need to call `result()` first...

(Also general advice is to not use globals if you can help it, which is 99.99% of cases, don't get into this habit it will likely bite you back...)

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized `record` variable in `submit()` which is causing the error.

You can use this:

```
def result():
    global record
    record=[('bread','50'),('cake','200'),('cold drink','20')]
    return record

def submit():
    record = result()
    for i in record:
        for j in i:
            if(j=='bread'):
                p=int(i[1]) * 3
    print(p)

a=submit()
```